# Заполнение матрицы с помощью функции

Tags: c#, ооп

Хотелось бы узнать, как можно заполнить элементы матрицы, используя некоторую функцию, которая генерирует числа в заданном диапазоне. В C++ данный код выглядит так:

```
double func(int, int) {
    return rand() % 12;
}

Matrix::Matrix(int row, int col, double (*func)(int, int)) {
    ...
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < this->row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this->col; j++) {
            this->arr[i * this->col + j] = func(i, j);
        }
    }
}
```

Как реализовать подобную логику в C#?

Comment: это точно C#?  Тег не перепутали?

Comment: Код из C++, но мне надо знать как реализовать подобный конструктор в C#

Comment: Обычно по таким задачам сразу возникает вопрос - а вы вообще пробовали сами решить задачу? Что именно не получилось. Вот вы например, знаете, как пишутся циклы в C#? Или вам нужно всё с нуля сделать?

Comment: Думал сделать с помощью делегатов, но немного не понимаю как, поэтому и спрашиваю. Мне нужно просто показать пример с подобной реализаций, дальше я сам разберусь.

Comment: есть такой тип `Func<int, int,double>` , вот его вам надо передавать в конструктор

Comment: "...Думал сделать с помощью делегатов..." - а вот почему нельзя было сразу вставить эти волшебные слова в текст вопроса? У читающих сразу бы пропало недоумение и желание поставить "-". ИМХО, выше в комментарии Вам дали решение, к которому нечего добавить https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.33.php

Comment: Я уже понял, спасибо